# Failed to read .txt file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file and I tried using the absolute path "C:\Users\(full path)\A3Data" and static paths (shown in code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream MyReadFile("A3Data.txt");

    if(MyReadFile.is_open()) //checks whether file is being opened
    {
        while (getline(MyReadFile, line)) //uses getline to get the string values from the .txt file to read line by line
        {
        cout << line << '\n';
        }
        MyReadFile.close();
    }
    else if (MyReadFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "A3Data.txt failed to open" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:
(contents in `A3Data.txt`)

Actual Output:

```
"A3Data.txt failed to open"
```

Double backslashing the absolute path e.g. `C:\\Users\\(full path)\\A3Data.txt` gives me the error too.

Changing the filepaths and ifstream-ing it to the different path also shows me the error.

When i tried to read my file from cmd, I cd'ed it to the full path and typed in the text file name. I could open & read it properly. Hence I feel that the w.r.x are accessible to me and I have rights to the file.

UPDATE:

I have figured out my issue. Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: Something is propably wrong with the file you're trying to open, are you sure the name is right, and that it's in the right directory?

Comment: Yes. I've even tried double backslashing the absolute path where my .txt file is stored at.

Comment: Can you check the file is at the same location as you are while executing code? Do you have proper access rights?

Comment: Yes I do. Checked the access rights at file properties. Shouldn't be a problem when i could open the file directly from cmd as an administrator.

Comment: It's possible that your program is not running at administrator level, which is why I suggested attempting to run it from the administrator command prompt. Either way you are looking at an issue with either; your permissions being incorrect for the program, or you have an invalid path to the file. There's really nothing else that could cause that problem, unless of course another program is currently using the file and holding it open (which is unlikely since you never stated it worked prior).

Answer (score 1):

You need to double backslash or declare your file path as a string literal. You can do this like:

```
string myPath = L"C:\Users\(full path)\A3Data.txt";
```

As a string literal, or

```
string myPath = "C:\\Users\\(full path)\\A3Data.txt";
```

As a properly escaped file path

If the above does not work and you have guaranteed that you have the proper paths to the file then you may not have proper rights to the file. You could try running a command line as administrator and then executing your code from that, if that also fails let us know.

Comment: Yes I tried that already. Since a single backslash functions as a 'break' in C++.

Comment: If that's the case then you most likely have an incorrect filename, also you need the extensions (I forgot them myself) so I edited my code above.

Comment: It should not be a problem with relative paths. And it may work differently on unix-like systems

Comment: He may be compiling and running his executable from a folder that does not contain the text file which would in fact cause the problem from relative paths, this can happen with some IDE's and also if project settings are incorrectly configured, which is why I want him to attempt a full path call instead.

Comment: That filepath in which i included the text file does indeed contain the text file but however it does not read it in properly. I'm still not sure as of how to resolve this error even when I tried double backslashing, moving the text file into different paths and reading the file from the other file paths, its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Try copying the full path from your system and using L"C:\Users\(full path)\A3Data.txt" instead, I have a feeling you are formatting it incorrectly.